# What information is needed to solve or approximate this simple equation?

Tags: linear-algebra, sequences-and-series, optimization, approximation

Suppose I have some vector $x = a + b = (a_0 + b_0, \dots, a_{n-1} + b_{n-1})$ of length $N$. Now, if only $x$ is known, what is the minimum amount of information that is needed to either solve or approximate what is $a-b$? Of course, if there is no any other information about $a$ and $b$ except their sum this cannot be solved.

To start, notice that the solutions of $a-b$ lie along the line $y = 2a - x$. To throw some idea, how much the number of solutions could be narrowed if I knew for example what is $\sum_{i=0}^{N-1} a_i - b_i$? The minimal information on $a$ and $b$ can be something else as well, if it's computable in linear time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to solve for $2N$ variables.  Your initial information about $a+b$ gives $N$ linear equations in these variables.  If you add more linear equations, you will need at least $N$ more to have a chance of solving.

The one you propose $\sum_i a_i-b_i$, is one linear equation.  Now you need $N-1$ more.

In the comments, you propose the $N$ linear equations $$C_K=\sum_{i=0}^K a_i-b_i$$
as $K$ varies from $0 $ to $N-1$.  If you know all of these, then indeed you can recover what you want.  In fact, you don't even need $a+b$ if you have all these.  You have $$a-b=(C_0,C_1-C_0, C_2-C_1, \ldots, C_{N-1}-C_{N-2})$$

Comment: I see. Would it help anything if there was some relationship between each $a_{i}$ and $a_{i+1}$ and $b_{i}$ and $b_{i+1}$? My $a$ and $b$ have temporal structure. More precisely I could probably find some $\delta$ so that $a_{i-1} - a_{i} < \delta$ for each $i$ (and the same for $b$).

Comment: Inequalities will not let you solve anything exactly unless they can be proved to be tight (i.e. equalities after all).  They do turn a shape that is unbounded in $2N$ dimensions into a shape that is bounded in some of them.

Comment: Actually, wouldn't I have the $2N$ equations if I save all the intermediate steps of the summation? I mean that $s_{i} = \sum_{n=0}^{N-1} a_{i} - b_{i}$ for each $i$ is computable in linear time.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification on the inequalities. I come from a computer science background, so I find all mathematics quite difficult.